# Reading next non-missiong observation's value in current observation

Tags: sas, proc

My question is quite similar to [reading next observation's value in current observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579865/reading-next-observations-value-in-current-observation) except that I want to read the next **Non-Missing** observation (in SAS).

For instance, this is my data set

```
data have;
   input ID Salary;
   cards;
10 1000
20 .
30 3000
40 .
50 .
60 6000
;
run;
```

And I am looking for something like this

```
ID Salary
10 1000
20 3000
30 3000
40 6000
50 6000
60 6000
```

As you can see, for ID's 40, the salary get the value from the next non-missing observation which is ,from ID's 60, 6000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked question gives several suggestions, most of which can be adapted to this.

For example, the accepted answer can be slightly modified.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if missing(salary) then
    do _i = _n_+1 to nobs;
      set have(keep=salary) nobs=nobs point=_i;
      if not missing(salary) then leave;
    end;
run;
```

You could also sort the data in reverse and use retain to accomplish the same.  That's probably more efficient if you have a lot of missingness.

Comment: Thanks again! May I ask  what do you do?

Comment: Interesting indentation style of the conditional block.  I like it, don't think I've noticed this before (seen some people with DO on same line as IF THEN, others with DO on separate line but not indented).  Indenting the DO clause and then of course indenting the content of the do block itself looks nice.

Comment: Thanks.  I often will do this by accident, sort of: I include the `then do;` but then later realize it's not needed and remove it.  But in theory that's how I'd indent it on purpose also.