# Looking ahead in SAS

Tags: sas, regex-lookarounds

I need to create a lead variable in my data set in SAS.

I used the simple method:

```
proc expand data=data out=data_lead method = none; 
convert rate; 
convert rate = rate_lead5  / transformout=(lead 5); 
run;
```

But SAS required more resources (My data is about 220 GB)

Is there any simple way to create a 5-step-ahead variable without utilizing so much memory ? Thanks !

Comment: Have a look at @Joe answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30332066/3972769

Comment: So there's no BY variable or anything else - just 220GB of data rows, all a single time sequence, and you're wanting 5 rows ahead pasted on?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, take a look at Joe's answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321413/reading-next-k-observation-from-current-observation/30332066#30332066) question. However, if you only need to read each record 5 steps ahead (rather than 5 variables 1-5 steps ahead) then you can use his technique but without a macro by just doing:

```
data data_lead ;
  merge data data(firstobs=5 rename=(rate=rate_lead5)) ;
run ;
```